# Custom scrollable timepicker in android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image: check Image]

I want to create a time picker as shown in the image. I have tried varoious fields but it didnt work.

Comment: I tried to implement one once, and it was way harder than expected. Can you try to alter the design to match android-defaults? Also, show what steps you already have taken on your journey to a solution

Comment: I had tried with the default time picker but the client wants the custom one. basically i just want the time picker without dividers and the middle row in a different colour. This is the basic need. I can provide the steps i have taken but its no use as i was trying to modify the native timepicker but it was not possible, that's why i am here to get help.

Comment: You can take reference from these libraries : https://github.com/commandiron/WheelPickerCompose
https://github.com/venshine/WheelView
https://github.com/yijiebuyi/3DWheelPicker

Comment: @Laser Can you please specify whether you want to implement this in XML or using Jetpack Compose?

Comment: I want this to implemented in xml as I have not learnt compose yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Ranjithkumar, but I needed that in bottom sheet with am pm. and I have created it. Here is how I have done it.

I have created a custom layout where I have used 3 number picker and to achieve the selected background behavior I have put a linear layout with the selected background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/horizontal_line"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            style="@style/semiBoldTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:text="@string/str_set_your_time"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/indicator" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horizontal_line_"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtTitle" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/selectedBG"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_selected_time"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/_30sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/hrsPicker"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/amPmPicker"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/hrsPicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/hrsPicker" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/hrsPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:selectionDividerHeight="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/numberPickerTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/minPicker"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalDivider" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/minPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:selectionDividerHeight="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/numberPickerTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/amPmPicker"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/hrsPicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalDivider" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/amPmPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:selectionDividerHeight="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/numberPickerTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/minPicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalDivider" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            style="@style/customButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_light"
            android:fontFamily="@font/urbanist_semibold"
            android:text="@string/str_cancel"
            android:textColor="#5E636D"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnApply"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hrsPicker" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            style="@style/mediumTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text=":"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/hrsPicker"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/minPicker"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/hrsPicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/hrsPicker" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnApply"
            style="@style/customButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_primary"
            android:fontFamily="@font/urbanist_semibold"
            android:text="@string/str_apply"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnCancel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hrsPicker" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Then I have made a custom time picker class which extends the bottom sheet dialog.

```
class CustomTimePicker(context: Context) : BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.BottomSheetStyle) {

    val binding = LayoutCustomTimePickerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val amPm = arrayOf("AM", "PM")
        binding.hrsPicker.apply {
            minValue = 1
            maxValue = 12
            wrapSelectorWheel = true
            setFormatter { it.formatTwoDigits() }
        }
        binding.minPicker.apply {
            minValue = 0
            maxValue = 59
            wrapSelectorWheel = true
            setFormatter { it.formatTwoDigits()}
        }
        binding.amPmPicker.apply {
            displayedValues = amPm
            minValue = 0
            maxValue = 1
            wrapSelectorWheel = true
        }
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

}
```

and then the final step. I have used it in adapter class like this.

```
 rvBinding.edtDayStartTime.setOnClickListener {
                val timePicker = CustomTimePicker(itemView.context)
                timePicker.apply {
                    binding.btnApply.setOnClickListener {
                        val startTime = "${binding.hrsPicker.value.formatTwoDigits()} : ${binding.minPicker.value.formatTwoDigits()}"
                        rvBinding.edtDayStartTime.setText(startTime)
                        slotTimings.dayStartTime = startTime
                        notifyDataSetChanged()
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }.show()
            }
```

Here how it looks
[image: custom timepicker Image]

Thank you guys for all the help you gave.❤

Comment: good work. If you have time, my kind suggestion - create a git repo for this custom time picker, it will helpful for our dev community.

Comment: sure i will do the same

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel, instead of writing custom time picker.
You can use [SnapTimePicker](https://github.com/akexorcist/SnapTimePicker) library

Add dependency:

```
implementation 'com.akexorcist:snap-time-picker:1.0.3'
```

Call the dialog and get the results:

```
SnapTimePickerDialog.Builder().apply {
    // 
}.build().apply{
    setListener { hour, minute -> 
        // Do something when user selected the time 
    }
}.show(supportFragmentManager, tag)
```

More customization available, you can set interval, minimum time etc.

Check github - https://github.com/akexorcist/SnapTimePicker

Only missing part is AM/PM not supports. You can implement this, if you spend few hours. Instead of starting from scratch you can go with this library.