# How to create a iOS scrollable time picker in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml

I need to implement a scrolling timepicker that should be as similar to this one as possible (it's an element from ios, to be frank).

[image: time picker reference]

Unfortunately, I haven't found such elements in material3.
I tried using the standard timePicker, but it's very hard to customize, I couldn't even put a font on it. Do you have any ideas how it can be done, maybe links to libraries? At the moment I am making ui on **View**

Comment: https://github.com/loper7/DateTimePicker
https://github.com/jaaksi/pickerview
check this and make a view as u like

Comment: try putting 3 number picker and try customizing that one. I built a custom timepicker you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77865655/custom-scrollable-timepicker-in-android-kotlin